# Is calling a classes' Init() method moot when Init() is empty?

Tags: c#, initialization

I'm maintaining an app with this code:

```
PlaytypusPacketGenerator crpg = new PlaytypusPacketGenerator();
ppg.Changed += new ProgressEventHandler(IncrementProgress);
ppg.Init();
```

The Init() called is empty:

```
public void Init()
{
}
```

Is it necessary, or beneficial somehow, to call an empty Init()?

Comment: Well, what is `PlaytypusPacketGenerator`? Is your own class? If so, it's just like any other method (nothing specific to `Init`). So yes, it's pointless (assuming you're never going to add something to the method).

Comment: I think the idea is that _some_ packet generators need to do initializations in Init(), but not all of them. Or maybe `PlaytypusPacketGenerator`'s Init() implementation is subject to change? But if this is all your own code and there's no need for init then just remove it.

Comment: There's not enough context here. For example, are you sure `Init()` isn't a virtual method? What about the type `PlaytypusPacketGenerator`? Could there be alternative implementations/versions of the type? How about code injection or other scenarios that might require a placeholder method? Empty methods often _are_ unnecessary. But the best answer can only be provided from the person who put the call to the empty method in, in the first place. Only they can distinguish between "I thought I might need it" and some genuine need.

Comment: So, since it's not hurting anything, I'll just leave it in.